# On VScode, why does my code immediately execute a exit code=1?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, exit-code

I am new to coding and was given an assignment to make a program that manages a banking account. I wrote and run my program on VSCode and it immediately initiates an exit code=1 and showed [these following errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PAct.png). I followed the instructions to download the compiler and program correctly with the extensions needed for C++, and their instructions verified that I installed it correctly.

I tried running my program on another IDE (replit) and it worked but does not have the functions I need to prove my work. Other than replit, I do not know any other IDEs that I could try without it costing something.

I mainly just need recommendations on how I can fix VS Code, if there is anything wrong with how I installed it, or another IDE that is less complicated to install without a monthly payment.

Comment: The linker is complaining it can't find stuff, you probably have multiple cpp files, use a build tool like Make, CMake,....

Comment: What platform are you using VSCode?  If it is Windows, you could use [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/community/) 2022 Community Edition.  No monthly payment.  If it is Macintosh, you could use [Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) 15.  Not sure on Linux.

Comment: Your problem is probably that you did not follow the instruction here on how to build more than 1 cpp file: [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_modifying-tasksjson)

Comment: ***if there is anything wrong with how I installed it*** Probably not,